# Rename tabs with same name in an Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename tabs in my large excel by using a cell value in each worksheet. The issue is, I would like to rename multiple tabs with the same name, which is not allowed. I am ok with adding a 1, then a 2 etc but am not sure how to do that.

For example if the cell value in 3 sheets is Ohio, then the tabs would be Ohio1, Ohio2, Ohio3.

The name of each sheet should be the value in A1, but I want to account for duplicate names.

The vba code to do it without accounting for the same name is:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = Range("a1").Value

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

On Error GoTo fixName

For Each ws In Me.Worksheets

ws.name = ws.Range("A1").Value


Next ws


Exit Sub
fixName:
ws.name = ws.Range("A1").Value & i
i = i + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However, that renames all of them according to A1 on the first sheet, and I would like to name each of them according to A1 on their own sheet.

Comment: I updated with a solution for that :-). Note however, that right now this will put a number after every name, not just duplicates. So you might end up with Indiana1, Ohio2, Ohio3, Indiana4, Iowa5, Ohio6.

Comment: I changed my answer. This should do what you want. The only weird behavior here is that it doesn't count how many times each name is used, it simply county the number of duplicates. 

So you could have Ohio, Indiana, Ohio1, Alaska, Alaska2, Iowa, California, Ohio3, Indiana4.

Also, if a1 is blank, the name of the sheet will simply be a number.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer what happens when `A5` has got a value like "Address w/o City"?? :)

Comment: @cyboashu. True, if there's an error in `A1` other than duplicate, this will crash an overflow.  Oops :p

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer, how strict OP's requirements are, but if you think about the problem , its not that simple. Many things can go wrong. :)

Comment: Oh Sure. I don't intend this to be the end-all perfect solution to this problem (and if you have a better answer, by all means edit it in / make a competing answer). I'm just hoping that this shows OP _a_ strategy to accomplish the goals. (This is actually my 3rd iteration of solution, as my answer's edit history will show).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RenameTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsName$, wsCount%, dict   ' $ is short for " As String" and % for " As Integer"
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each ws In Sheets
        wsName = ws.Range("A1").Value
        wsCount = IIf(dict.Exists(wsName), dict(wsName) + 1, 1)
        dict(wsName) = wsCount

        If wsCount = 1 Then
            ws.Name = wsName
        Else
            If wsCount = 2 Then Sheets(wsName).Name = wsName & 1 ' optional to rename the previous Ohio sheet to Ohio1
            ws.Name = wsName & wsCount
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```